# Update a boolean to its opposite in SQL without using a SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Is it possible to upgrade a bool field by telling it to update the field to the opposite of what it is without having to select the value - check it then update accordingly which seems long winded...

A pseudo example of what i mean

```
UPDATE `table` SET `my_bool` = opposite_of(my_bool)
```

Currently i have to SELECT my_bool in one query then do a quick check on its value so i can update the table in a second query.

I was hopeing to cut that down to a single query if that is possible ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

use `NOT`

```
UPDATE `table` SET `my_bool` = NOT my_bool
```

Comment: So that makes true = false and false = true! Neat! :) thanks!

Comment: Got to wait 13 minutes to tick your answer - should be shorter if upvotes is high enough :P

Comment: is it `SET active = NOT active` or `SET active = NOT(active)`

Comment: if prefer `SET active = NOT active`

Comment: ok it seems then my syntax error is related to having an INNER JOIN then

Comment: can you show me the whole query? one more thing, what is the datatype of `active`?

Comment: this is mysql right? i see the backticks around columns. here's the correct query, `UPDATE  users t1 
  INNER JOIN user_setings AS t2
   ON t1.tid=t2.id
SET  active = NOT active 
WHERE  t2.uid= ?  AND t1.id=?`

Comment: actually your syntax if for `sql server` :D

Answer (score 29):

```
UPDATE `Table` SET `my_bool` = 1 ^ `my_bool`
```

Comment: This was the better option for me, for some reason I was getting errors when trying to use NOT in a INSERT INTO.....SELECT command, thanks

Answer (score 4):

FOR Microsoft SQL Server Kindly use `~` sign.

For example:

```
UPDATE [AspNetUsers] SET IsDisabled = ~IsDisabled WHERE Id = '001893bd-4e4c-4ce1-9cd1-3b155a733774'
```