# MySql Updating boolean value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, boolean

When I try to test manually updating the boolean value in my MySql table before implementing it into a ruby script, I get a match but no changes :

> `UPDATE calls SET ended = NOT ended WHERE incoming_Cid = '1234567890';`
>
> `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`
>
> `Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0`

Unless I'm mistaken, this looks like correct syntax to me.

I looked at other threads concerning this issue (flipping boolean values) like [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183012/update-a-boolean-to-its-opposite-in-sql-without-using-a-select)

### What would be a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Would this work : UPDATE calls set ended = !ended

Comment: What's the type of the ended field? A quick test table here using `bit` is properly flipping the value

Comment: Though @RahulTripathi has a query that works, yours is better Frank because it sets the Boolean 'ended' to the opposite that it currently is at, no matter what the circumstance. Rahul's just sets it to 0. Write it as an answer so I can pick it as my accepted answer!

Comment: Marc, the ended field is `BOOLEAN`, and `SET ended = !ended` works! Don't know what `bit` is though :/

Comment: Quite puzzling ?!? Like @MarcB I've done a quick test and it works using your initial syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90fe2/1

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite sure why it didn't work out the first time, the syntax seemed correct. Nevertheless, it works now so I can modify the boolean value for ended calls with my call monitoring script.

Comment: @Zagstrug: `boolean` is a synonym for `tinyint(1)`. could be something weird going on because a bit field is literally just a bit. boolean is actually an 8bit field that's limited to displaying only 1 digit (the `(1)` business)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work :

```
UPDATE calls set ended = !ended WHERE incoming_Cid = '1234567890';
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your `ended` value was an SQL `NULL` value. The logical `not` of a null value is still null, so the DB is properly reporting "no changes", because the value in `ended` didn't change - it started out as null, and was still null:

```
mysql> create table foo (x boolean);
mysql> insert into foo values (null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> update foo set x=not x;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> update foo set x=not x;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Note the `Changed: 0`. But once you reset x to a non-null value:

```
mysql> update foo set x=true;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update foo set x=not x;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

rows start changing immediately.

Comment: Ohhh. That would explain the issue, because the ended is in fact a `NULL` value. So `not` of null would still be null ...Silly me...

Comment: Yep. null is basically poison. Without taking special precautions, any operation involving null themselves become null. Treat it as "unknown", and when you mix known and unknown, you end up with unknown.

Comment: So what happens if i have ended `BOOLEAN NOT NULL`? EDIT: Should I just change it to data type `int` and have it start at 0 so that when I do `ended = !ended` it goes from 0 (false) to 1 (true)