# SQL: INSERT 1 if value=0 and 0 if value=1

Tags: php, sql

I have data from an SQL query that is 'fileUnavailable' and need to insert into another table that is 'fileAvailable.' The values are either 1 or 0 and I need to do an SQL insert. Since fileUnavaiable and fileAvailable are opposite, I'd need to change the first value to either 1 if it's 0 or 0 if it's 1. Originally, I was thinking to just do an if, else statement to change the value, but that seems bulky and seems too simple for there not to be a method already.

I'm mostly curious as to whether or not SQL has something like !(fileUnavailable) but works for 1 and 0 because these values are ints in my db.

Pseudo:

```
INSERT INTO table (fileAvailable) VALUES ( NOT($fileUnavailable));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hint with `ABS`:

```
UPDATE table SET field = ABS(field - 1)
```

So if `field` is `1`, then `field - 1` is `0`, `abs(0)` is still `0`.

And if `field` is `0`, then `field - 1` is `-1`, `abs(-1)` is `1`.

[`ABS()` man page.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)

For query you provided in a question:

```
INSERT INTO table (fileAvailable) VALUES ( ABS($fileUnavailable - 1) );
```

Comment: What if the value is 0 though? Are you saying, use this in an if,else statement?

Comment: 0-1 is -1 and then its ABS is 1 and nope, no if statement is required. This query is complete as it is

Comment: Oh, I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

I found this from another stack overflow question.

```
INSERT INTO `table` SET `my_bool` = NOT my_bool
```

[Update a boolean to its opposite in SQL without using a SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183012/update-a-boolean-to-its-opposite-in-sql-without-using-a-select)