# Update status in database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

In my project I have one task related to the SQL server database.

```
Employee
======================
id  Name  Active
1   a     0
2   b     0
3   c     1
4   d     1
```

Here is my table in a grid format and when the admin click on the status update button I want to update the status in one GO. For example here, Id 1 and 2 have 0, and Id 3 and 4 have 1. So, when the admin clicks on the button I want to update the field and make something like this as shown below.

```
Employee
======================
id  Name  Active
1   a     1
2   b     1
3   c     0
4   d     0
```

Now Id 1 and 2 becomes 1 and Id 3 and 4 become 0. Please suggest. How to update the field.

Comment: use boolean in place of a number in Active  attribute refer to this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183012/update-a-boolean-to-its-opposite-in-sql-without-using-a-select

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update a boolean to its opposite in SQL without using a SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183012/update-a-boolean-to-its-opposite-in-sql-without-using-a-select)

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag the RDBMS of interest.

Comment: As a trainee you will be better of doing some research, taking an SQL tutorial, learning about select, insert, update & delete, than just having someone give you the answer on a plate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to *toggle* the 0/1 values in the `Active` column, then you may use:

```sql
UPDATE Employee
SET Active = 1 - Active;
```

Another way, using the modulus:

```sql
UPDATE Employee
SET Active = 2 % (Active + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarity purpose, using CASE expression.

```sql
UPDATE Employee
SET Active = CASE Active WHEN 1 THEN 0 
                         WHEN 0 THEN 1
                         ELSE NULL
                         END
```

Answer (score -2):

if active = 0 and not active makes opposite of 0 which is 1 and vice versa. Hope it works.

```
UPDATE Employee SET Active= NOT Active
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your SQL.